# Solving $Ax=b$ : Is row reducing augmented matrix same as multiplying by inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I need to solve a series of equations where $A$ is a matrix, $x$ is an unknown vector, and $b$ is a known vector.  I initially set up an augmented matrix $[A|b]$ and thought I could solve for $x$ by row-reducing the augmented matrix.  My professor told me I should just multiply $A^{-1}b$ to get $x$, which makes sense... but why wouldn't row-reducing the augmented matrix work, and how would you prove it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Row-reduction always works, even when $A$ has no inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row reduction works for solving a system of equations like you mentioned. You can prove using the equations themselves
$$a_{11}x_1+...+a_{1n}x_n=b_1$$
$$\vdots$$
$$a_{n1}x_1+...+a_{nn}x_n=b_n.$$
Each reduction step results in a set of equations which have equivalent solutions. So if you can get the matrix into row echelon form and you have a system that is still solvable, then any of its solutions will be a solution to your original equation. In particular if the matrix is invertable then you'll arrive at
$$x_1+0x_2+...+0x_n=b'_1$$
$$0x_1+x_2+0x_3+...+0x_n=b_2'$$
$$\vdots$$
$$0x_1+...+0x_{n-1}+x_n=b_n'.$$
So $x=b'$ where $b'$ is the vector you get after row reduction.